# Issue with fragment layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

when I pass data from `activity` to `fragment` i get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Si4.png

Why are fragment overlapped? I need only fragment with the checkbox checked.

this is the code when i pass data:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putIntegerArrayList("oki", hm);
            bundle.putIntegerArrayList("okiquantitapizze", hm_quantitàpizze);

            System.out.println("PERO:" + bundle);
 MyListFragment2 myFragment = MyListFragment2.newInstance(hm,hm_quantitàpizze);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, myFragment);
            transaction.commit();
```

MYLISTFRAGMENT2:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        System.out.println("BUNDLES1 prima:" + bundle);

        bundle=getArguments();

        System.out.println("BUNDLES1 dopo:" + bundle);



        if (bundle != null) {
            strtext2 = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("daje");
            System.out.println("BUNDLES1 prima:" + strtext2);

            quantitàpizze2 = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("daje2");
            System.out.println("BUNDLES1 prima:" + quantitàpizze2);

        }

}




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the custom_spinner_items for this fragment
        //super.onDestroy();


        SharedPreferences settings = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();


        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_2_2, container, false);





        return rootView;


    }




    public static MyListFragment2 newInstance(ArrayList<Integer> hm, ArrayList<Integer> hm_quantitàpizze) {
        MyListFragment2 fragment = new MyListFragment2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putIntegerArrayList("daje", hm);
        args.putIntegerArrayList("daje2", hm_quantitàpizze);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

FRAGMENT_LIST_2_2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/acab"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"


    >
    <!--android:background="@color/white"-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listvieww"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>




</FrameLayout>
```

ITEMS OF LISTVIEW:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/welcome"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/numero_tavolo"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/lbl_name"
                    android:textSize="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    />
              <!--  <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
                    android:layout_width="122dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dip"
                    android:background="@color/btn_login"
                    android:text="@string/btn_logout"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:onClick="logoutUser"

                    />-->

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabss"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpagerr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
     <!--   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/pero"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>-->

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

IF I PUT

android:background="@color/white" into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/acab"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"

    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listvieww"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>




</FrameLayout>
```

i get this:

[image]

Comment: Please share your fragment xml code @androidiano

Comment: post your items xml code

Comment: i added it!!!!!

Comment: ok now you made me hungry..

Comment: @mohammadrezakhalifeh i added it now

Answer (score 0):

you should use in fragment background some color

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/acab"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listvieww"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>




</FrameLayout>
```

I can see in this image its not overlapped right.

[image]

Comment: where i must put this??

Comment: add it to parent layout in fragment xml

Comment: check my updated answer and try with that. Hope it will not overlap

Comment: check my code update...i tried like you advice me but i have the sam eproblem

Comment: check my answer